# Require и абсолютная адресация.

Tags: require

вот так у меня не работает(не существует файл)

```
require('/config.php');
```

код ниже РАБОТАЕТ(судя по вашим комментариям я не так ясно это написал в начале)

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config.php";
```

Вопрос: должен ли по идее работать первый случай?
ADD: этот код содержится в файле /pages/main.php, а congig.php находится в корне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый не должен работать - это абсолютный путь от  корня OS , если ваш сайт каким-то образом chrooted в DOCUMENT_ROOT, тогда конечно / будет работать. лучший способ это задать константу где-нибудь в index.php

```
define('BASEDIR',dirname(__FILE__)."/");
```

и соответственно использовать

```
require_once BASEDIR."config.php";
```

Comment: Мужик, спасибо тебе. Чётко и ясно ответил на вопрос, который я задавал. Вопрос: должен ли по идее работать первый случай? И вот наконец-то ответ: нет, не должен. Как я обожаю таких людей!

Answer (score 2):

Вижу недопонимание, как работает сервер с путями, и как видит ссылки браузер.

В файловой системе, как и на сайте есть `абсолютные` пути, так и `относительные`. `Абсолютные` пути - это те пути, которые начинаются от "корня". Т.е. пример:

Допустим у нас есть сервер, который берет файлы из папки `Z:\server\localhost`

> Файл в системе: `Z:\server\localhost\images\myphoto.jpg`
>
> Файл, если смотреть через браузер: `http://localhost/images/myphoto.jpg`

Как видим, различия на лицо.

---

Относительные пути - это те пути, которые задаются относительно какого-либо документа.

Пример с тем же файлом `myphoto.jpg` для браузера:

> В директории
> `http://localhost/images/` есть файл
> `index.php`, в котором есть ссылка:
>
> `<a href='myphoto.jpg'>фото</a>`, ссылка относительно документа `index.php`, который находится в этой же папке.

И для сервера:

> В директории
> `Z:\server\localhost\images\`  есть файл
> `index.php`, в котором есть:
> `require('../config.php');` 
> Т.е. мы поднялись на директорию выше относительно файла `index.php`

---

В вашем примере "корень" сайта на сервере еще нужно найти, обычно делают так:

есть некий файл `config.php`, который лежит в корневой сайта. В нём объявляют константу, в которой указывают абсолютный путь до корневой сайта со стороны сервера:

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__);
```

Дальше становится очень удобно управлять подключениями (`include`, `require`, ...), Т.е.:

```
require(ROOT.'/engine/boot.php'),
```

Comment: поставлю палец вверх, ничего нового для меня тут нет, но может кому полезно будет.

Comment: @Dazar пытался ответить, что нет, не будет работать первый вариант :)

Answer (score 0):

```
require('./config.php');
```

так попробуй

Comment: не работает. сейчас дополню вопрос.

Comment: относительная адресация допустима и в require и в include (и в тех что с once)

Comment: странно, а с двумя точками попробуй

Comment: С двумя точками работает, но это, как я понимаю, мы просто поднялись на уровень вверх.

Comment: А перед `require` `chdir(..)` поробуйте поставить.

Comment: да. но вообще конечно лучше делать абсолютную адресацию. я обычно использую архитектуру, где в index.php просто подгружаются модули (модуль как отдельная страница). так вот в самом верху index.php определяю глобальные адреса для всех классов, функций и т.д, а затем просто к глобальному адресу добавляю название того файла который мне нужен

Comment: chdir('..');
    require('../config.php');  
Вот так работает, но разве это правильно? и чёрт возьми, что мы вообще сделали??

Comment: я не вижу здесь ничего неправильного, установили текущий каталог. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.chdir.php

Comment: я не понял, что значит хотелось пойти от корня? тогда используйте глобальную адресацию

Comment: Сейчас выключил XAMPP, включил денвер, проверил, результат тот же. может он вообще не обязан так работать?  
буду пользоваться require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config.php";, пошло оно всё к чёрту.

Comment: выведете и сравните что у вас в переменной, а что в конфиге.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати `DOCUMENT_ROOT` в настройках сервера устанавливается (в данном примере `apache`),

```
NameVirtualHost localhost:80
# the example
<VirtualHost mysite.localhost:80>
# and absolute path
DocumentRoot "/srv/www/mysite/"
</VirtualHost>
```

И от этого уже сама переменная `SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` пляшет.

Comment: Так в том-то и прикол, что с $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] всё правильно работаёт, а с этим слешем почему-то не хочет.

Comment: <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    #General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost:443
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    <IfModule log_config_module>
        CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    </IfModule>  
Тут всё правильно, там всё правильно, только слеш тупит.

Comment: ну по факту должно работать так: `require('./config.php')`, либо так: 
`require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php';`

Comment: А кстати вот такая ссылка в том же файле работает на ура. <a href='/config.php'>fsdf</a>